# replacing using regex python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a sentence like this

```
s = " zero/NN  divided/VBD  by/IN  anything/NN is zero/NN"
```

I need to replace all the words with tags to just tags . Output should be

```
s = "NN VBD IN NN is NN"
```

I tried using regex replace like this

```
tup = re.sub( r"\s*/$" , "", s)
```

but this is not giving me the correct output . Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the output you want:

```
tup = re.sub( r"\b\w+/" , "", s)
```

`\b` is matching a word boundary, followed by `\w+` at least one word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) and at least the slash.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
tup = re.sub( r"[a-z]*/" , "", s)

In [1]: s = " zero/NN divided/VBD by/IN anything/NN is zero/NN"
In [2]: tup = re.sub( r"[a-z]*/" , "", s)
In [3]: print tup
 NN VBD IN NN is NN
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the first answer but this can be modified as [A-z] to change uppercase letters also .

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` character group matches all whitespace characters, which doesn't seem what you want. I think you want the other case, all non-whitespace characters. You can also be more specific on what is a tag, for example:

```
tup = re.sub( r"\S+/([A-Z]+)" , r"\1", s)
```

This replaces all non-whitespace characters, followed by a slash and then a sequence of uppercase letters with just the uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tup = re.sub( r"\b\w+/(\w+)\b", r"\1", s)
```

on either side of my regex is \b meaning "word boundary", then on either side of "/" i have \w+ meaning "word characters".  On the right we group them by putting them into parentheses.

The second expression r"\1" means. "the first group" which gets the stuff in parentheses.